# Radio Boxes Clickable Images

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I am trying to figure out how I would setup a group of images to work like radio buttons. Basically when a user clicks a image it wil display a check mark below to indicate it has been selected. I could accomplish showing the check mark I believe by a onclick event and some css. But what would be the best way to do this with ASP.net I also need to transmit the data to the server via a form. [image]

Comment: You can use hiddenfield to store the imgId or value to show which image has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would populate a hidden field with the resulting value of the selection via client-side code. Then you just read that value in your code behind on submit.